# Spring security : redirecting to the login page after loggin in

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am implementing spring security using the java configuration.

Poviding the necessary config classes here.

SpringSecurity.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/auth/login")
            .usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and().httpBasic();

}

}
```

WebConfig.java

```
public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { SpringConfig.class,SpringSecurity.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new String[] {"/"};
}

}
```

AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException,
        ServletException {


    System.out.println(authentication.getName());
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/home/homePage");
}

 }
```

SpringConfig.java is where all the datasource and other packages scan related stuff are defined, i guess that won't be needed here.

Problem is that when hit the login page url (contextPath)/auth/login, it shows me login page. But,
after i hit the login button it redirects me to the same login page.

I am providing the login.jsp here.

```
<form:form action="../home/homePage" class = "form-horizontal">
    <legend id = "loginLegend">LOGIN</legend>
    <hr style="border: none; height: 1px; color: blue; background: #244363;"/>
        UserName: <br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="j_username" style = "width: 90% !important; margin-left : 20px;"/><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" class = "form-control" name="j_password" style = "width: 90% !important;margin-left : 20px;"/><br>
        <button id = "loginButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Ofcourse it will as the form is submitted to `../home/homePage` instead of the url handling the login.

Comment: @M.Deinum : I have provided the requestmapping for ../home/homePage in the controller.

Comment: what exactly are you expecting it to do when you hit the login button?

Comment: @Aeseir : It should take the user to the homepage as mentioned in the form action.Controller method is provided for that.

Comment: You checked that the user is authenticated after you hit the login?

Comment: @Aeseir: that will be taken care by spring securityfilter chain right? as i have provided in memory authentication in config class.

Comment: Nice that it is a controller but you seem to miss some knowledge on how the web works. The form is submitted to your controller url, but that is protected, show a login screen, which is submitted to a protected login, well you get the drift. You should post to `/login` and have the login filter redirect to your homepage, not submit to the homepage.

Comment: For the redirect you don't need a success handler just set the `default-target-url` and if you always want to go to this page (instead of the requested page) set the `always-use-default-target` to `true`

Comment: @M.Deinum: /login is springsecurityfilter? and i tried always-use-default-target . In which i provided ../home/homePage. Is it correct?

Comment: Doh, that was for xml not java config.. you should use the `loginSuccesURL` for java config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a few issues with what you have now and how you are expecting it to work.

Firstly, you need to point your login page to the url that will process the login form (you can have custom if you want).

Secondly, if you want the user to always end up at "/home/homePage" then you should just add `loginSuccessURL("/home/homePage");`

Otherwise what you can do, is just set the antMatcher("/home/homePage") with a role expected and it will always request login unless the user is authenticated.